# What iOS version comes preinstalled on the iPhone 7?

Tags: ios, iphone

I know that if you "Restore from iCloud backup" from a backup made with iOS 10.0.1, the iPhone 7 makes you install the update first, so it must come with a version before 10.0.1. Do you know which version this is?

Comment: Wouldn't it be 10.0?  I thought the iPhone shipped to distributors prior to 10.0.1 becoming available.

Comment: I read something recently that said the iPhone 7 comes with iOS 10.0 and the update for pre-iPhone-7 is iOS 10.0.1. I'm guessing the update is 10.0.1, then.

Comment: Yeah, I assume some version of 10.0.0, but what build number if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just activated my iPhone 7 and it came preinstalled with iOS 10.0 (saw that on an email from Apple Sign-In alert) and it prompts you to upgrade to iOS 10.0.1 even before proceeding with your setup.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea what build number?

Comment: @kjg when Apple sends these emails they don't include the build number but I'll try not to update the next new iPhone and see if I could get you that

Comment: @kjg that build version is 14A346